# Cómo decir la expresión «difficult cookie to crumble» en español

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

¿Cuál sería una expresion equivalente en español de la expresión anglófona *difficult cookie to crumble*?

Comment: Modifiqué tu pregunta para que encaje mejor con este sitio (preguntar el significado de una frase en inglés es para english.stackexchange.com )

Comment: La frase *difficult cookie* no equivale a *tough cookie*.  Significan la misma cosa, pero *tough cookie* presenta un juego de palabras que se pierde con *difficult cookie*

Answer (score 2):

Es una mezcla de dos expresiones en inglés (ojo: es más frecuente con *tough* en vez de *difficult*), pero últimamente no es infrecuente escucharlas así combinadas.

La principal es *a tough nut to crack* (literalmente sería *una nuez difícil de partir/sacar*) cuyo equivalente en español es *un hueso duro de roer*.

Desconozco una frase para decir *a tough cookie* pero significa una persona tenaz, determinada, decidida, resistente.

Así que depende del contexto exacto (si es una persona o una situación, si se quiere connotaciones positivas o neutra-negativas), la traduciría en una de aquellas maneras.

Comment: Yo conozco "That's the way the cookie crumbles" que viene a significar "La vida es así". Ejemplo "ME gusta esa chica, pero creo que a ella le gusta otro. Qué se le va a hacer. La vida esa así..."

Comment: @Diego es cierto, podría ser una combinación de las tres, aunque faltando contexto no lo podemos saber sin duda

Comment: De acuerdo con Diego.  Viene de "That's the way the cookie crumbles".  En este sentido, "tough cookie" tiene cierto valor humorístico, porque puede signicar una galleta difícil de masticar.

Answer (score 0):

Sin buscar la traducción literal, yo diría que el espíritu de la frase hecha vendría a ser similar a la de "duro de roer"

Answer (score 0):

En español usamos la expresion principalmente *Hueso duro de roer*.